# Generate random dates within past 12 months

Tags: java

I'm using this Java code to generate random dates:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now().minus(Period.ofDays((new Random().nextInt(365 * 70))));
            Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Is there a way to limit the random dates within last 12 months?

Comment: Will removing `* 70` do it?

Comment: Not sure if correct but there are 60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour, 24 hour in a day and 365 days in a year. Which give use 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 seconds in a year. What about generating a random number in a range `actual Timestamp - (60 * 60 * 24 * 365)` and `actual timestamp` and convert that to a Date ?

Comment: what if it was a leap year

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want to deal with timezones, leap years, leap seconds etc. yourself, so I recommend using the java.time library (java 8 and up).

If you only want `LocalDate`-precision, you could get any day within a specified range like this:

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate then = now.minusYears(1);

long difference = now.toEpochDay() - then.toEpochDay();
int randomDifference = random.nextInt((int) difference);

LocalDate randomDate = then.plusDays(randomDifference);
```